# Ruby, скрипты, backend и аудио

Tags: swift, ruby

Есть аудиофайл. Изначально он разбит на звуковые дорожки в приложении на iOS.
На backend'е есть скрипт, который склеивает дорожки в цельный файл.
В админке нет проблем с запозданием звука.
При скачивании на комп, открытии через хром админки или открытии файлов в приложении, звук запаздывает на 1-4 секунды.
Не понимаю, в чём загвоздка.

Comment: в слаке запоздание на долю секунды, на убунту 3 сек на винде чуть больше двух

Comment: Эм, в скорости интернета, например? Вообще мало что понятно, многочисленные ошибки в тексте тоже понятности вопроса не добавляют

Comment: Так в хроме стартует четко аудио в 10.37, сафари позже, скачанный аудиофайл стартует еще позже